# Python console "EOF when reading a line" error using raw_input

Tags: python, eof, ubuntu-15.10

Using Pyhton 2.7 and Ubuntu 15.10

I faced an annoying issue when using raw_input in a python console of some IDES like ninja-ide or genay (console plugin). They cast a "EOFError: EOF when reading a line" and don't allow to write.

Meanwhile developing a *.py file, the execution is correct and don't fail. Python, as executing from terminal, doesn't fail as well as console using IDLE.

Any solution? Thanks. I couldn't find exactly this issue neither in StackOverflow nor Internet.

Comment: I guess the environment you're running in does not have stdin, i.e. keyboard input.  Maybe you can configure this in the platform's settings somehow?

Comment: Thanks John. I'll do my best to find it out.